# Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 15,1 (2018) Grub error

Tags: grub2, macbook

How can I install it? What's going on there?

[image]

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /
>      target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will  not boot.
>
> [OK]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MacOS still installed?
If so you might need to manually mount the EFI partition as it may not have been detected automatically. GRUB needs it to be installed to `/boot/EFI` in this case that folder is mounted under `/target` by the installer.

If you don't have MacOS then you should have been prompted to partition the disk and create one, which would then be mounted automatically. If that didn't work you could try manual partitioning or mounting.

To mount the EFI partition you can just use `mount /dev/sdxY /target/boot/EFI` before trying to install GRUB. To find the "x" and "Y" in `/dev/sdxY` look in the partitioner or use a command like `lsblk`.

It might also be possible to select an already existing EFI partition in the installer and mark it to be used. The last time I installed on a Mac I used the text installer, this option might not be available in the live version.

Note: The partitioning tools and command line programs seem to call the EFI partition "ESP".

Another option could be to skip GRUB entirely and use a bootloader like [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) which can also boot MacOS.

Comment: MacOS is still installed. Im giving it a shot again, will install ubuntu 19.10 onto the external SSD and then after its having the fatal error il boot into the Live USB and try installing grub manually